# Android: Add new edittext onto new lines

Tags: android, dynamic

I have added a button and an edittext onto a framelayout. The problem is I appear to lose the functionality of being able to click the button. When I click the button, the keyboard appears for the edittext. How can I add button/editext objects into a layout so that they appear on a new row and do not affect each other. I was using the padding option to move them about, but this still causes the button to be non-clickable.

Here is my code: -

FrameLayout reportLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.reportDetailLayout);

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Button executeButton = new Button(this);

executeButton.setClickable(true);

executeButton.setOnClickListener(handleOnClick(executeButton));

EditText text1 = new EditText(this);

executeButton.setText("Execute");
executeButton.setMinimumHeight(10);
executeButton.setMinimumWidth(150);

text1.setId(1);
text1.setHint("Enter Value");

executeButton.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
text1.setPadding(12, 70, 0, 0);

executeButton.setLayoutParams(params);
text1.setLayoutParams(params);

reportLayout.addView(executeButton);
reportLayout.addView(text1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FrameLayout` will cause Views to overlap. Try `LinearLayout` with `setOrientation()`.

And you don't use padding for placement. *Padding is not same thing as a margin*.